# How to check in karate if a node contains the expected value from the json response

Tags: cucumber, karate

The scenario is that I have got the following JSON response,say for eg :

```
[
    {
        "a": "a",
        "b": "a",
        "c": "a",
    }
    {
        "a": "ab",
        "b": "ab",
        "c": "ab",
    }

]
```

Now I want to check if the response contains "ab" in "b" node. 
In Karate , I am not getting how to go about it.

Given path 'url'
When method get
Then status 200
And match response == **??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you read the doc carefully, Karate has a lot of flexibility in this regard. Here below are a few examples, you can paste them into your `*.feature` file and see these working for yourself:

```
* def response =
"""
[
    {
        "a": "a",
        "b": "a",
        "c": "a",
    },
    {
        "a": "ab",
        "b": "ab",
        "c": "ab",
    }
]
"""
* match response[1] contains { b: 'ab' }
* match response contains { a: 'ab', b: 'ab', c: 'ab' }
* match response contains { a: '#ignore', b: 'ab', c: '#notnull' }
* def expected = { b: 'ab' }
* match response contains '#(^expected)'
```